# Al refrescar la página, no queda activo el tab seleccionado

Tags: javascript

Cuando refresco la página no se queda *cliqueado* en el menú seleccionado. Estoy usando tabs de bootstrap5 y js, no quiero usar jquery.

MENU TABS

```html
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <a href="#tab1" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab"  >Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <a href="#tab2" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" >Profile</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">...</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">...</div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        var tabEl = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]'));
        
        tabEl.forEach(function(tab) {

            tab.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

            
                localStorage.setItem('activeTab', e.target.getAttribute('href'));

                var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
                var mitab = document.querySelector('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]');
                
                mitab.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
                    event.target // newly activated tab
                    event.relatedTarget // previous active tab
                        //event.target.tab('show')
                    event.target.show()
                })

            });


        });

    })
```

Nota: al utilizar localstorage no logro que la clave "active" se quede activada; cuando refresco la página se regresa al principio.

Comment: Hmmmm, se ve que cada vez que termina de cargar la página, en el localStorage estás _seteando_ el "activeTab". ¿Cuándo preguntás si esa propiedad ya fue _seteada_ previamente?

Comment: si logro ha setearlo asi localStorage.setItem('activeTab', e.target.getAttribute('href'));

Comment: Lo sé... Es lo que mencionaba en mi comentario :) De nuevo: _¿cuándo preguntás si esa propiedad ya fue "seteada" previamente?_

Comment: previamente no he seteado, solo lo he echo de esa forma como esta ahí, tendría que abrir otro foreach y sear solo ahí?

Comment: Pensá en lo siguiente: en el 'DOMContentLoaded', la primera vez, estás estableciendo (_seteando_) el valor de "activeTab". Al recargar la página, se vuelve a ejecutar el 'DOMContentLoaded' y... ¡estás volviendo a _setear_ el valor! Por eso te hacía la pregunta capciosa: _¿cuándo preguntás si esa propiedad ya fue "seteada" previamente?_

Comment: exactamente como  dices, cuando carga la pagina se sigue seteando el valor en el 'DOMContentLoaded'

Comment: Te estaba dando una pista de cómo podés resolverlo :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Agrega id a los link de la cabecera

```
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation" >
   <a href="#tab1" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" id="tab-header-1" >Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <a href="#tab2" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" id="tab-header-2">Profile</a>
</li>
```

2. Script

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    //verificamos si existe un tab guardado
    var activeTab= localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if (activeTab != null) {
       var tab = new bootstrap.Tab(document.getElementById(activeTab));
       tab.show();
    }

    //guardamos el id del tab cuando cambia
    document.getElementById("myTab").addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', event.target.getAttribute('id'));
    })
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono pero con atributo "href", fue muy bueno, solo fue cambiar eso y quedo genial.